# What sould be a http response code for lack of PHP session based authorization

Tags: php, http, authorization

I am writing a small website. There is PHP session based authorization. What HTTP response code should I send, if a user doesn't have access to a certain page?

Is `412 Precondition Failed` a good idea? I think `401 Unauthorized` is good only for a http authorization. `400 Bad Request` and `403 Forbidden` looks too general.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**`403 Forbidden`** means "the name/password you gave is invalid for this URL" - that's what you want.

`401 Unauthorized` means "give me name and password".

`412 Precondition Failed` is something completely different (related to conditional requests; [see the RFC](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.24))

and `400 Bad Request` means "huh? what are you talking about?" (request is malformed and server doesn't know what to do with it)

See also: [RFC 2616 - HTTP 1.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4)

Note: If you want to show your own "you are not allowed to do this" page, make sure that it's over 512 bytes, else IE will show its own, so-called *friendly* error message instead  (see e.g [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1492444/ie-7-not-showing-my-custom-401-page) and [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/218155)).

Answer (score 3):

I would use 403. It means what it says: the user is forbidden to see the page.

Comment: ... it doesn't get any simpler than that.